# disable "Continue in a new Chrome profile" popup

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, chrome-profile

Every time I sign-in into new gmail account I get this popup asking if I want to create a new Chrome profile which sometimes get very irritating. Is there anyway to disable it?

In `chrome://flags/` option there are couple of options (New profile picker & Profile creation flow with sign-in) which I think could work but I am not really sure, Because I don't want to mess-up chrome profile settings as I use it extensively.

Comment: [Same question in Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/158438/55191)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** the solution below used to work but the flag is not available anymore. From Chrome 93+ it's not experimental anymore, thus it can't be disabled.

---

That behaviour is implemented in the Chrome's core dice_web_signin_intercept_app.js and yes, it can be disabled. This is the related flag: chrome://flags/#dice-web-signin-interception

The two flags cited above (*New profile picker* & *Profile creation flow with sign-in*) are completely unrelated.

Please note: the flag will be removed in Chrome 93+.

[image: chrome flags screenshot]

Comment: I no longer see this in chrome://flags.  Did they remove the flag?

Comment: Same here, Chrome #93.0.4577.63

Comment: Gone for me too. Uuugh.

Comment: No flag either in `98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, nor the official flag. Looking for the solution...

Comment: It just can't be disabled anymore.